# javascript alert синхронность или задержка выполнения скрипта

Tags: javascript

Хочу перегрузить стандартное поведение alert. Делается это просто:

```
function alert(_m){
    //code 
    // предположим здесь я рисую окошко из div элементов и одной кнопкой, просто дизайн меняю.
}
```

Вопрос в том, как мне задержать выполнение функции, пока мой пользователь не выполнит в моем окне нужные действия. Задержка не подходит, так как это самый худший вариант.

Сам я полагаю, что есть определенный способ управления сценарием, и можно как то приостановить его, а потом с точки останова или другой точки продолжить.

П.С.: firebug как то позволяет дебагить, значит существует механизм...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, Firebug - это все-таки не просто скрипт, а расширение, имеющее доступ к API платформы (например, Mozilla). Потому и остановы в указанных точках он делает с помощью движка. Во-вторых, у браузеров есть такое понятие как "UI thread" - это поток, разделяемый (в смысле "shared") UI-событиями на странице и пользовательским JS на этой же странице. Это разделение означает, что нельзя одновременно выполнять JS-код и выдавать пользователю отзывчивую страницу. Можно организовать нечто похожее и рабочее (так обычно и делают) с помощью `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()`, но по сути это лишь откладывание на потом - это не запуск отдельного потока в полном смысле этого слова, это, скорее, перенесение части кода в "будущее" все того же UI-потока.

Из вышеприведенного можно сделать вывод, что на пользовательском JS создать блокирующую функцию, чтобы она работала в точности как `alert()`, нельзя. В конце концов, вам понадобится нечто вроде бесконечного цикла для проверки какого-нибудь условия, который займет всю работу UI-потока. При этом вам нельзя будет использовать `setInterval()`, так как тогда ваша `alert()` не будет блокирующей.

Возможно, в мои размышления вкралась ошибка, буду рад любым возражениям.

Comment: Не могу не согласиться, но пока воздержусь, потому как усиленно копаю в эту сторону! Могу лишь помечтать о преимуществах блокирующих функций!))

Comment: Я долго и упорно копал и теперь полностью с тобой согласен: нельзя. <img src="/vote/31701/up/" width="1px"/><img src="/vote/30730/up/" width="1px"/><img src="/vote/22250/up/" width="1px"/><img src="/vote/19593/up/" width="1px"/>

Comment: @org да я давно знал что нельзя :)

Answer (score 1):

Есть дурацкий, но вариант - прописать callback:

```
function alert(x, c){
    prompt(x);
    if(c) c();
}
alert('test', function(){alert('stop');});
```

А если вы выводите сообщение div'ами, можете повесить callback на кнопку ОК.

Comment: Это уже давно знакомы способ! Кстати, сэр, у Вас зацикливание!)

Comment: У меня зацикливание? Да не может такого быть).  
А чем этот способ не угодил?

Comment: Мягко говоря не все программисты понимают колбаки. Вот для них было бы неплохо, да и профессионалам было бы комфортнее программировать!